# Как сохранять данные из html страницы в приложении Android?

Tags: android, jsoup, хранение-данных

Есть таблица (http://studydep.miigaik.ru/index.php) с расписанием универа.
Я парсю её с помощью jsoup и могу получить строки / столбцы.
Как мне хранить эти данные из таблицы?

Идея такая - юзер выбирает факультет, курс, группу, приложение парсит эту таблицу и отображает в фрагментах по дням пары.

Если это делается с помощью БД, то какой и как это будет удобнее всего реализовать (хранить по дням? по группам?) ?

Comment: Ну а в чем проблема, сохраняйте во встроенной СУБД, либо на удаленной СУБД, но тогда вам нужно писать Web-сервис

Comment: Вопрос про структуру самой этой СУБД, как грамотно её составить?

Comment: Мне сделать под каждую группу отдельную таблицу (отдельный класс, расширяющий DBHelper) и при выборе определенной группы как-то из этой таблицы считывать значения?

Comment: не совсем понял вас, касательно фразы: Мне сделать под каждую группу отдельную таблицу... Как я понял вас: Например есть группа ИСТ-104 и ИСТ - 105, для каждой из них нужно создать таблицу с расписанием. Так вы подумали?

Comment: Да, это я предположил, что может, сделать такую структуру. Но может это и глупость

Comment: Групп < 500 суммарно

Comment: у вас нет навыка проектирования баз данных. Для вашей задачи нужно создать несколько таблиц (факультет, курс, группа и занятие)
В первых 3 таблицах содержатся возможные варианты, а в последней хранится ссылки на значения в тех таблицах

Comment: Как только происходит дублирование строковых данных (не идентификаторов), то вам нужно создавать новую таблицу (сущности), и ссылаться но возможные варианты в новой таблице, чтобы база данных у вас была нормализована

Comment: Конечно нет, иначе зачем же я спрашиваю)
Занятие - это таблица со всеми (вообще всеми) занятиями, откуда по ключам группы, факультета и курса я буду получать занятия?

Comment: А что вы бы посоветовали почитать по этой теме? Нужно разобраться, а то понимания нет совсем. Последнее ваше сообщение не понял совсем.

Comment: Ну давайте под вашим понятием "занятие" будет дисциплина, это таблица в которой два параметра - идентификатор и название. В этой таблице хранятся все варианты предметов. Теперь создадим таблицу занятие (ну т.е по сути "пара"). В этой таблице у нас несколько параметров: id (собственное), id_group (ссылка на запись в таблице группы), id_discipline(ссылка на запись в таблице дисциплины)

Comment: Я даже не знаю, что вам посоветовать, найдите какой-нибудь курс онлайн. В университете это дисциплины Управление данными и Базы данных, там изучается SQL и проектирование баз данных

Comment: Если вы можете установить локальный сервер с MySQL, я бы вам скинул базу данных, чтобы вы посмотрели как это выглядит, так как я похожее приложение пишу

Comment: Или пройдите любой из курсов https://openedu.ru/course/spbu/DTBS/ или https://openedu.ru/course/spbstu/DATAM/

Comment: Это вам даст базовые навыки понимания проектирования баз данных и использования SQL

Comment: Спасибо большое! Начну первый. Надеюсь, получится понять

Comment: Если вы установите себе MySQL или используете хостинг, я бы мог скинуть копию своей базы данных, чтобы вы посмотрели бы в качестве примера, но без знания SQL вы далеко не уйдете

Comment: У меня установлен MySQL. Я не знаю, тут помоему нет чата, что нужно, чтобы вы скинули?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, сделал всё очень просто:

Парсинг таблиц с помощью:

```
Element innerTable = doc.select("select").first();
```

Создаю объекты для каждого из типа:Группа/Факультет/Курс

```
fakList.add(new Fak(namefak, val));
```

Ну и отображаю.
При необходимости кэширования - кэшируются ответы с сервера.